# Refer to the current page number, but not \thepage, but the real absolute

Tags: page-numbering, counters

I want to get the real page number. If I use `\thepage`, I get problems, when I change the pagenumbering. For pagenumbering `gobble`, it disappears, if I change from `arabic` to `roman`, it resets the counter. There must be actually some internal counter like `\p@count` (I made that up). What is it?

The following example should show 13 on the last page.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `xassoccnt` provides a mean to force a stepping of an associated counter each time a driver counter is stepped as well -- the driver counter is `page` here.

This has an advantage over the `totcount` or `lastpage` packages, since the associated counter `realpage` (any name will do, but `section` etc. is unwise, of course ;-)) is not reset (unless explicitly done so with `\setcounter`) -- As such, it counts the total absolute values of pages.

So even in case of `\pagenumbering` commands, this does not have an effect on the `realpage` counter.

Please note that `page` is an unrealiable counter in some sense!

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newcounter{realpage}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{realpage}
}

\begin{document}
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

A version with `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` (needs `xassoccnt` v.1.2. and above)

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalrealpage}
\NewDocumentCounter{realpage}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage,totalrealpage}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{realpage}{1}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
In diesem Dokument sind insgesamt \TotalValue{totalrealpage} Seiten!

Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage
Seite \therealpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This means, there isn't a real internal counter. So this has to be tweaked.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I know of none, but this does not mean there is none, of course!

Comment: if you're willing to process the file twice, it should be possible to place an anchor on the page with a label, then evaluate `\pageref` in the next cycle.  not trivial or immediate, but generally accurate.

Comment: You say unreliable. What does this mean. I actually just want to print the real last page count to the aux-file within `\AtEndDocument`

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The page label will only hold the number of the page as reported by `\thepage`, which is reset by `\pagenumbering`, but it will not give the total number of pages

Comment: @barbarabeeton doesnt seem to be bad, but it would mean, that I have to process three cycles, since I already have two. And I would have to take care of each circle not to do any error calculations.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: It depends on your position on the page. Use the `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` feature of `xassoccnt`, so you know the total number of pages at the begin of the document (needs two runs!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, of course, floating stuff. It will be printed after everything to the aux-file, so this should be safe. I just used another example as a MWE, that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 6):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `abspage` module provides access to an "absolute page number" property. Together with the `lastpage` module, you can extract the last absolute page number using `\zref[abspage]{LastPage}`. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref}

\begin{document}
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage
\newpage
Seite \thepage

Last page: \zref[abspage]{LastPage}

\end{document}
```

The interface to use `\zref[<prop>]{<label>}` requires the `user` module. Any specific page's absolute page number (other than `LastPage`, say) can be obtained using a `\zlabel{<label>}` and subsequent `\zref[abspage]{<label>}`.

Answer (score 4):

The `memoir` class provides two macros, namely `\lastpage` and `\lastsheet` which will print the page number of the last page and the number of sheets of paper required for printing the document single sided. To date I have not heard of any problems with these. They can be used like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,...]{memoir}
...
\begin{document}
...
The last page is number \lastpage\ and requires \lastsheet\ of A4
paper for printing single sided.
\end{document}
```

There is also a `\thesheetsequence` macro that prints the current number of sheets like `\thepage` which prints the current page number.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally there is a counter. `\c@page` (which is defined as  `\count0`) and you can access its value:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}\makeatletter
Seite \the\value{page}--\the\c@page --\the\count0
\newpage
Seite \the\value{page}--\the\c@page --\the\count0
\end{document}
```

But you must be careful as its value can be wrong due to the asynchronous typesetting. After \newpage as in your example everything is fine, but in normal paragraphs it can be one off.

Comment: This doesnt work. It is reset on a change of the pagenumbering.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: Well it is the counter underlying \thepage. If you want the absolute page number, zref-abspage offers the counter \c@abspage, and the package count1to  `\count1`.