# Cross-referencing: check that all cross-references are to earlier objects

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a huge LaTeX document with my lecture notes for a maths course; every now and then I change the order of the sections.

I want to make sure that all cross-references to, for instance, theorems are in "chronological order": referring in section 7 to stuff from section 5 is fine, but I don't want to use in a proof of section 5 references to results that won't be proved until section 7.

Is there a package that checks whether cross-references are to labels defined earlier or later in the document than that particular reference?

Comment: you could compare the current page with the the ref's one in \pageref

Comment: I thought about that, but it would involve changing numerous \refs and \eqrefs to \pagerefs and then, if all looks well, changing back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof of concept (it would require extensive work if `hyperref` is involved):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@label\label
\let\latex@ref\ref
\def\label#1{\global\@namedef{LABEL@#1@USED}{}\latex@label{#1}}
\def\ref#1{%
  \ifcsname LABEL@#1@USED\endcsname\else
    \@latex@warning{Forward Reference '#1'}%
  \fi
  \latex@ref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{a}

This refers to \ref{a} and to \ref{b}.

\section{B}\label{b}

OK.

\end{document}
```

The log file would contain

```
LaTeX Warning: Forward Reference 'b' on input line 19.
```

Comment: I could temporarily comment out (%) hyperref! What is the problem with combining it with hypperref? That the latter redefines the labelling/referencing commands?

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution that seems to work, though not within subequations.
It uses zref for absolute page numbers, see [How to find absolute page number as an integer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24236/how-to-find-absolute-page-number-as-an-integer) and [Refer to the current page number, but not \thepage, but the real absolute](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317427/refer-to-the-current-page-number-but-not-thepage-but-the-real-absolute)
You will find warnings in the log file for all not wanted cross-references.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\let\oldeqref\eqref
\let\oldlabel\label
\newcommand\mylabel[1]{%
  \oldlabel{#1}%
  \zlabel{#1}%
}
\renewcommand\label[1]{%
  \mylabel{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \zref{#1}%
  \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{abspage}<\value{realpage}
    \GenericWarning{}{Warning: Backwards refence '#1' on page \thepage}%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
  (\zref{#1})%
  \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{abspage}<\value{realpage}
    \GenericWarning{}{Warning: Backwards refence '#1' on page \thepage}%
  \fi%
}

\def\label@in@display#1{%
      \ifx\df@label\@empty\else
      \@amsmath@err{Multiple \string\label's:
          label '\df@label' will be lost}\@eha
      \fi
      \mylabel{#1}
      \typeout{XXX #1 XXX}
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{realpage}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{realpage}
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section{Sec~1}
\begin{align}\label{eqR1}
    x &= 1
\end{align}

Text~R1\label{textR1}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Sec~2}

\begin{align}\label{eq1}
     x &= 1
\end{align}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
      x &= 1\label{eqS1} \\
    y &= 1\label{eqS2}
      \\
    z&=1
    \\
    z&=10
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Text~1\label{text1}

\newpage

\begin{itemize}
  \item Equation~R1: \eqref{eqR1}
  \item Equation~1: \eqref{eq1}
  \item Equation~S1: \eqref{eqS1}
  \item Equation~2: \eqref{eq2}  
  \item Text~R1: \ref{textR1}  
  \item Text~1: \ref{text1}
  \item Text~2: \ref{text2}
\end{itemize}

\newpage 

\section{Sec~3}

\begin{align}\label{eq2}
    x &= 2
\end{align}

Text~2\label{text2}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: The cross reference could be at the top of a page and the referenced object at the bottom of the same page.